# Generate script Insert in .net

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, insert, conditional-statements, database-scripts

I have problem when trying generate script insert with specific condition.

So far I am already trying this step.

1. Add references Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo and Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
2. Add reference in code Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
3. Add this to script.

   ```
     var srv = new Server(@"localhost\SQLEXPRESS");
     var db = srv.Databases["Northwind"];
     foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table tab in db.Tables)
     {
         foreach (string s in tab.Script())
         {
             File.AppendAllText("sql_insert_conditioanl.sql", s);
         }
     }
   ```

Script "sql_insert_conditioanl.sql" contain only to create database and create table that exist in database "Northwind".

So I do research about this problem. Trying change method "Script" without parameter to parameter "ScriptingOptions" ref [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.tableviewbase.script%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx). I still confuse to using parameter Scripting Options.

Then also trying using protected method. But since it protected, I can't test method (like: Method "ScriptAlter").

Regard

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate scripts for all database objects - for example indices, stored procedures, views etc. See this [article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1833) (and its related articles) for getting started.